# Deserialize json array with both fields and dictionary

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

I want to create a C# class to deserialize this JSON using Newtonsoft.Json:

```
[
    {
        "awb": "2205900120010",
        "oras destinatar": "",
        "continut": "",
        "nume confirmare": "",
        "data confirmare": "",
        "ora confirmare": "",
        "awb retur": "",
        "0": {
            "id": 0,
            "status": "AWB-ul nu a fost predat catre FAN Courier",
            "data": "",
            "ora": "",
            "oras": "",
            "traseu": ""
        }
    },
    {
        "awb": "5345899260009",
        "oras destinatar": "Tamaseu",
        "continut": "COMANDA 16201",
        "nume confirmare": "Szilagyi Ileana",
        "data confirmare": "13.12.2018",
        "ora confirmare": "17:16",
        "awb retur": "",
        "0": {
            "id": 1,
            "status": "Expeditie in livrare",
            "data": "12.12.2018",
            "ora": "14:46",
            "oras": "Lugoj",
            "traseu": "Expeditia a fost preluata de catre FAN Courier in data 12.12.2018 14:46."
        },
        "1": {
            "id": 1,
            "status": "Expeditie in livrare",
            "data": "12.12.2018",
            "ora": "19:35",
            "oras": "Lugoj",
            "traseu": "Expeditia a plecat din hub-ul FAN Courier Lugoj spre hub-ul de destinatie in data 12.12.2018 19:35."
        },
        "2": {
            "id": 2,
            "status": "Livrat",
            "data": "13.12.2018",
            "ora": "10:46",
            "oras": "Oradea",
            "traseu": "Expeditia a fost preluata spre livrare de catre curierul din orasul Oradea in data 13.12.2018 10:46."
        },
        "3": {
            "id": 2,
            "status": "Livrat",
            "data": "13.12.2018",
            "ora": "17:16",
            "oras": "Oradea",
            "traseu": "Ultimul status al expeditiei: livrat in data 13.12.2018 17:16."
        }
    }
]
```

Already tried to deserialize with

```
var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<AwbTrackingResponse>>(text);
```

but the `Events` remains null.

```
public class AwbTrackingResponse
{
    [JsonProperty("awb")]
    public string Awb { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("oras destinatar")]
    public string DestinationCity { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("continut")]
    public string Content { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("nume confirmare")]
    public string ConfirmedName { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("data confirmare")]
    public string ConfirmedDate { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("ora confirmare")]
    public string ConfirmedHour { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("awb retur")]
    public string AwbReturn { get; set; }
    // ???
    public Dictionary<int, AwbTrackingEvent> Events { get; set; }
}

public class AwbTrackingEvent
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("status")]
    public string Status { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("data")]
    public string Date { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("ora")]
    public string Time { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("oras")]
    public string City { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("traseu")]
    public string Route { get; set; }
}
```

I expect the `Events` dictionary would be also populated, but now it remains null. I'm not sure if this type of deserialization is supported out of the box by Newtonsoft.Json library. If yes, then maybe I can get a hint of what needs to be changed on my C# classes, and if not, then maybe I will get an alternative to convert this JSON data to be usable from C# code.

Comment: I'm not sure there's a simple or clean way to do this. You could replace `AwbTrackingResponse` with a `Dictionary<string, object>` and manually process the properties. Or more likely you will need a custom converter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Json.Net has an "[Extension Data](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2013/05/08/json-net-5-0-release-5-defaultsettings-and-extension-data)" feature which can cope with this situation.  If you mark a dictionary with a `[JsonExtensionData]` attribute, the dictionary will be populated with the key-value pairs from the JSON for which there are not properties defined in the class.  The catch is, the dictionary has to be declared as either `Dictionary<string, object>` or `Dictionary<string, JToken>`.  Since you want `Dictionary<int, AwbTrackingEvent>`, I would suggest this idea:

1. Define a private `EventData` property of type `Dictionary<string, JToken>` in your class to capture the extra data from the JSON, marking that with the `[JsonExtensionData]` attribute.
2. Change the public `Events` property to convert the `EventData` dictionary to and from `Dictionary<int, AwbTrackingEvent>`.  Mark this property with `[JsonIgnore]`.
3. Then, just deserialize as normal and it should work as you want.

Here is what it would look like in code:

```
public class AwbTrackingResponse
{
    ...

    [JsonExtensionData]
    private Dictionary<string, JToken> EventData { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public Dictionary<int, AwbTrackingEvent> Events
    {
        get
        {
            return EventData?.ToDictionary(
                kvp => Convert.ToInt32(kvp.Key), 
                kvp => kvp.Value.ToObject<AwbTrackingEvent>()
            );
        }
        set
        {
            EventData = value?.ToDictionary(
                kvp => kvp.Key.ToString(),
                kvp => JToken.FromObject(kvp.Value)
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a working demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Dz9HY0

Comment: Yup, that solves the problem. I just tested it this morning and works fine. I'm very happy that Json.Net is flexible enough to deal with this kind of json data. Thanks Brian

Answer (score -1):

You have a few things wrong with you Json string. 
First in your key elements you have spaces, e.g.

```
"data confirmare": "",
```

this should be:

```
"data_confirmare": "",
```

Use json2sharp.com and jsonlint.com to sort it out.
So far I have the following to help you along:

```
[{
    "awb": "2205900120010",
    "events": [{
        "0": {
            "id": 0,
            "status": "AWB-ul nu a fost predat catre FAN Courier"
        }
    }]

},
{
    "awb": "5345899260009",
    "oras_destinatar": "Tamaseu",
    "continut": "COMANDA 16201",
    "nume_confirmare": "Szilagyi Ileana",
    "data_confirmare": "13.12.2018",
    "ora_confirmare": "17:16",
    "awb_retur": "",
    "events": [{
            "0": {
                "id": 1,
                "status": "Expeditie in livrare",
                "data": "12.12.2018",
                "ora": "14:46",
                "oras": "Lugoj",
                "traseu": "Expeditia a fost preluata de catre FAN Courier in data 12.12.2018 14:46."
            }
        },
        {
            "1": {
                "id": 1,
                "status": "Expeditie in livrare",
                "data": "12.12.2018",
                "ora": "19:35",
                "oras": "Lugoj",
                "traseu": "Expeditia a plecat din hub-ul FAN Courier Lugoj spre hub-ul de destinatie in data 12.12.2018 19:35."
            }
        },
        {
            "2": {
                "id": 2,
                "status": "Livrat",
                "data": "13.12.2018",
                "ora": "10:46",
                "oras": "Oradea",
                "traseu": "Expeditia a fost preluata spre livrare de catre curierul din orasul Oradea in data 13.12.2018 10:46."
            }
        },
        {
            "3": {
                "id": 2,
                "status": "Livrat",
                "data": "13.12.2018",
                "ora": "17:16",
                "oras": "Oradea",
                "traseu": "Ultimul status al expeditiei: livrat in data 13.12.2018 17:16."
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

]

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have any control over how that json data is produced. I just need to consume it from my C# code, so I've been trying to find an elegant solution for deserialization.